# Gwt and html5 multithreading / WebGL support

Tags: multithreading, gwt, webgl

I am currently researching GWT as a means to develop web apps for a future project, and the more I read, the more I like the features it provides. Yet I am not quite sure what features of HTML5 are fully supported. I am more interested in multithreading (the new worker threads that work straight from JavaScript), WebGL rendering through the canvas element and possibly audio. 
 
If these features are not supported yet, does anyone know any good libraries that are somewhat fast / stable for such features, or if it's possible to create custom widgets / wrappers, or a combination of writing code in GWT and pure JavaScript.

I know there are simpler ways of implementing these through various plugins, but I want something which is fully complaint with open web standards, meaning it has to run straight from the browser, without any plugins. That is why GWT seems like the best candidate, it "compiles" straight into JavaScript and uses features only from the official specifications of html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT is ultimately compiled to javascript, so it has all the features of Javascript.

GWT provides classes (Widget, etc..) that wrap javascript/DOM functionality, but this is limited to standard functionality.

You can access all new/non-standard functionality (WebGL, ..) via [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html). JSNI allows you to call JS, be called by JS and access properties/objects.

So if what you need can be coded in JS it can be coded in GWT via JSNI.